# Add view in tab bar project - xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, tabs, tabbar

I have a x-code project made by tab bar. On `AppDelegate.m` I create three buttons for each view:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController3=[[[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

When I am on the first view I want to create a button that calls another view:

```
-(IBAction)btnPush{
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

but when the new view comes up it covers the tab bar on the botton. How can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Adding `UIViewController` in `UITabBarController` add `UINavigationController` as following

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController3=[[[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
```

Now add your ViewController to NavigationController

```
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController1, navController2,navController3];
```

It will add Navigation Controller in TabBarController

Comment: there is a way to do the same things without the navigation controller?

Comment: i dont know if any, i am not sure about it. but most probably there is no way.